# what is role of BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

error : 1 validation error detected: Value 'BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket' at 'code.s3Bucket' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[0-9A-Za-z.-_]*(?

what is the role of  BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket

```
Conditions:

  HasBucketKey:
    Fn::Not:
      - Fn::Equals:
          - {Ref: BucketKey}
          - ''
  HasBucketName:
    Fn::Not:
      - Fn::Equals:
          - {Ref: BucketName}
          - ''

Parameters:
  BucketKey: {Default: '', Type: String}
  BucketName: {Default: '', Type: String}



Resources:

  OriginAccessLambdaRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action: ['logs:CreateLogStream', 'logs:PutLogEvents', 'logs:CreateLogGroup']
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
              - Action: ['cloudfront:*']
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
          PolicyName: CloudFrontOAIPolicy
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role





  OriginAccessLambda:
    DependsOn: [OriginAccessLambdaRole]
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::If:
            - HasBucketName
            - {Ref: BucketName}
            - BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket
        S3Key:
          Fn::If:
            - HasBucketKey
            - {Ref: BucketKey}
            - BATS::SAM::CodeS3Key
      Description: Creates an origin access identity
      Handler: handlers.oai
      MemorySize: 2048
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [OriginAccessLambdaRole, Arn]
      Runtime: python3.6
      Timeout: 120
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function

Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31**
```

this my cloudFormation template

IAM role is creating successfully but while lambda creation above error coming.

thanks

Comment: Where did you get this from? This is probably part of some CFN macro.

Comment: yaaa   i am working as intern at amazon  you are right it is part of one CFN. but above part is not dependending ohter things . so why it is not working individually

Comment: what  are these 2 things doing here 1. BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket and BATS::SAM::CodeS3Key . is there any resource to regarding these stuff

Comment: Its not working because you need to call macro transformation on your template. The macro will substitute  `BATS::SAM::CodeS3Key` to correct values. I can't find any documentation on `BATS` but it is used for example here  https://pastebin.com/z08JFJK9

Comment: Note in the link `Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31` This is the AWS SAM macro that will transform template and substitute these values to correct ones. But I can't find any aws info about that. Maybe some old, undocumented feature?

Comment: If you're an intern at amazon and you're posting internal stuff you could get in a lot of trouble you should delete this and any other questions like it immediately.